New SSD doesn't show in UEFI boot but only in Legacy and won't accept Windows 11
system:
HP Pavillion gaming

Processor:Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-8400 CPU @ 2.80GHz   2.81 GHz
SSD: Kingston FUry Renegade NVMe 1TB
RAM: Kingston Fury 2x16GB DDR4 3200MT/s CL16 Beast
MB: HP 843B
OS: Windows 11 Home
BIOS version: AMI F.42, UEFI

As a part of my PC upgrade i have bought new RAM and SSD (because my old HDD has latency up to 40 000 ms). I've encountered two problems:

I make USB instal drive with window media creation tool,I have formated the SSD to be clean (and it should be in GPT partitions), I plug in the USB, disconnect the old HDD, the USB boots up fine, SSD is shown with some partitions (i delete them to create one storage space*), the instalation starts, finishes after about 5 minutes, the PC restarts and there is no OS installed. The SSD othervise works, it's shown in myPC and i can move files to it just fine. That led me to start digging into bios and that's where I noticed problem number 2

The SSD doesn't show under UEFI boot options but only under legacy options which I guess means it's not formated in UEFI wich it should be.


Anyone knows what I'm doing wrong? I've been stuck on this for over a month now and even my IT friends have no clue.
*if I don't delete them it won't let me start the instalation

The only way Legacy options would be shown in the UEFI firmware settings is if CSM [Legacy] Mode is enabled, which it should never be since it's sole purpose was to allow distros to boot that lacked EFI boot circa <2017 (Windows has supported EFI boot since Win7). Disable CSM Mode and ensure the Windows install media has been created for EFI boot (Rufus is recommended to create the install USB, especially since it removes a lot of the forced requirements for Win11)

Windows 11 doesn’t support Legacy Mode. You should disable it.

Having recently done the same, what worked well for this PC was: 1. Image the existing internal HDD to an external HDD (Macrium Reflect was used, but dd or any other imaging software should work). 2. Remove the HDD and replace with SSD. 3. Using "Rescue" USB, restore image to SSD. As soon as the PC rebooted, it worked!
